# How to write rspec test cases to cover failure of object save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have following code

```
@support_report.notes = params[:support_report][:notes]
  if @support_report.save
    redirect_to admins_support_reports_path, notice: t('admins.support_reports.add_notes.successfully')
  else
    redirect_to admins_support_reports_path, alert: t('admins.support_reports.add_notes.no_change')
  end
```

In this am just updating 'notes' attribute which is not having any validation.
I have to cover 'else' part inside rspec coverage.
How can I do it, please suggest some way

Answer (score 1):

```
it "should re-render new template on failed save" do
    SupportReport.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(false)
    post 'create'
    assigns[:support_report].should be_new_record
    response.should render_template('new')
end
```

Comment: please provide explanations to your answer